# UglifyJS not mangling props and state properties

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, uglifyjs

Is there a reason why `UglifyJS` doesn't mangle the properties of `props` and `state` in my `React` code? I'm using the default options.

`flippedSentence`, `errorMessage` and `lastSentences` are all properties of `this.state`.

Or is this fully intended?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason of not mangling properties of objects by default (in particular of `props` and `state`) is that it can actually break your code (and it seems that it will break due to [official documentation](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2#cli-mangling-property-names---mangle-props)).

You can mangle object properties using additional param, but:

> **THIS WILL PROBABLY BREAK YOUR CODE**. Mangling property names is a
>   separate step, different from variable name mangling. Pass
>   `--mangle-props` to enable it. It will mangle all properties in the input code with the exception of built in DOM properties and
>   properties in core JavaScript classes.

If you still want to mangle props - you can try control what to mangle and what exclude from mangling using [options](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2#command-line-options) for `--mangle-props` like `reserved`.

Also (just to note) in official documentation about [optimizing performance](https://reactjs.org/docs/optimizing-performance.html#browserify) when using `react` they don't use props mangling.